# View below recyclerview is not clickable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi I am working on showing a view (publisher ad) below recycler view. Recycler view has some empty views to show publisher ad when it comes to related index. Currently I can click on any recycler view item and I am able to see my ad, but I cannot click on ad. How to achieve this? Here is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/parallax_ad_unit_id"/>

    <widgets.AppSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <widgets.AppRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager" />

    </widgets.AppSwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you unable to click on com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView or some other ads showing in recyclerview?

Comment: @bilal it's the requirement from my company. If the adview would be an item of recycler view, yes, it becomes clickable. But I want to click it under recycler view.

Comment: By "under", do you mean behind it, on the z-axis? 'cause that's what your layout looks like it's doing.

Comment: @MikeM. yes that's what I meant.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure you're going to be able to do that easily. Also – and this is not strictly programming-related advice – but I think Google's policy won't allow that. I've never used ads, personally, but from the many questions I've seen here about them, Google is rabid about not having their ads blocked in the slightest way.

Comment: As Mike said, its against the policy of google ads.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `FrameLayout` the `PublisherAdView` will be overlapped by `AppRecyclerView` or `AppSwipeRefreshLayout`, so when you click on item, that click event will be listened by `AppRecyclerView1 every time.

Try after changing the position of your `RecyclerView` and `AdView`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<widgets.AppSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <widgets.AppRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager" />

</widgets.AppSwipeRefreshLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/parallax_ad_unit_id"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but your solution didn't work. When the ad becomes visible, my recycler view is no longer scrollable - adview prevents it's touches. also adview stays in front of the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout` for `activity_main.xml` which allows to place views
on top of others (in Z axis).

ex: `SwipeRefreshLayout` is the top most view here.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_posts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create two item layouts for two types of recycler view types

ex:

`item_normal.xml`, `item_transparent.xml` (where layout background is transparent that allow to see the layout below the surface area)

Setting `android:clickable=false` in `item_transparent` does not stop triggering the click event on transparent item, so use [communication flow using interfaces](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), to bring the other view(ad) to the front when clicked on transparent item.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RvAdpater.OnItemClick {

    private lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
    private lateinit var adView: View
    private lateinit var rvPosts: RecyclerView

    override fun onClick() {
        bringAdFront()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupRecyclerView()
        setupSwipeRefreshLayout()
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        rvPosts = findViewById(R.id.rv_posts)
        rvPosts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val rvAdpater = RvAdpater()
        rvAdpater.setListener(this)
        rvPosts.adapter = rvAdpater
    }

    private fun setupSwipeRefreshLayout() {
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_posts)
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing...")
        }

    }

    private fun bringAdFront() {

        adView = findViewById<View>(R.id.ad)
        adView.bringToFront()
    }

    // to go back to the normal recycler view(which is inside swipe refresh layout)
    // when back button is pressed
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val parent = swipeRefreshLayout.parent as ViewGroup
        parent.removeAllViews()
        parent.addView(adView, 0)
        // at last add swipe refresh layout which is the container of the recyclerview
        parent.addView(swipeRefreshLayout, 1)
    }
}
```

**RvAdapter.kt**

```
const val TAG = "RvAdpater"

class RvAdpater : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var listener:OnItemClick


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val viewNormal = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_normal, parent, false)
        val viewTransparent = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_transparent, parent, false)

        return when(viewType){
            0 -> NormalViewHolder(viewNormal)
            2 -> TransparentViewHolder(viewTransparent)
            else -> NormalViewHolder(viewNormal)
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 10

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        when(getItemViewType(position)){
            0 -> {
                val normalHolder = holder as NormalViewHolder
                normalHolder.tv.text = "Post"
                normalHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on Normal item")
                }
            }
            2 -> {
                val transparentHolder = holder as TransparentViewHolder
                transparentHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

                    listener.onClick()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun setListener(onItem:OnItemClick){
        listener = onItem
    }

    interface OnItemClick{

        fun onClick()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = position % 2 * 2

    class NormalViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val tv:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_post)
    }

    class TransparentViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

Checkout branch: [with-swipe-layout](https://github.com/kaushalyap/rv-bg-click/tree/with-swipe-layout)

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<widgets.AppSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <widgets.AppRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ad_view" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            ads:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</widgets.AppSwipeRefreshLayout>
```